# Browser specific behavior of JSF while I have one ajax listener and another action listener for command button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have

```
<p:inputText id="sales-person">
        <p:ajax event="change"
            update="employee_name" listener="#{quoteBean.rebuildServiceDataList}"/>
</p:inputText>
```

... and

```
 <p:commandButton id="confirm-button" process="#{breadcrumb.breadcrumb_base_name}" value="#{shop_msgs['continue.label']}"  actionListener="#{quoteBean.showPayUI}" />
```

Skipped some part of code for understanding.

Basically when I change something on the input text it will call some ajax method to fetch some data, validate etc. And when I click on command button it will submit.

In Chrome browser if I type something and directly click on submit button, it is actually first firing onchange event, this calls the ajax then action listener for command button will execute.

But in case of IE if I do the above mentioned step, it will only execute the onchanage and calls the ajax method. The actionListner will not be invoked.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Edit 1: I tried even with onclick in command button, even that is not called in case of IE. When I try to click on button only the onchange event of text box is executed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the developer tools of IE browser by pressing **F12**.
Are there any error messages in console? What happens with the ajax call?
My first thought, I doubt that there is a lack in your Bean or similar, because basically it works.

From my experience (in connection with datatables), IE has indeed more troubles dealing with java script than Firefox or Chrome for example.

Comment: Thanks for  the reply. There is nothing on the browser console. If there is a lack in bean then it should not work in case of chrome too. And in case of IE on first direct click on button, it is executing the ajax, as I am moving focus out of the input text box, and on second click on the button it is submitting. But if I focus out of the input box by clicking somewhere else and then clicking on the button it is submitting.

Comment: Have you tried using on your button **immediate=true** or **type=submit** ? Probably it helps :/

Comment: try to remove your <p:ajax> tag and just do a submit (for detecting the source of your problem). I can imagine that your commandButton will work after this and ajax is disturbing your request submit. If that is true, give <p:remoteCommand> a chance to handle your ajax request instead of <p:ajax>. More infos here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml